# python 3.8 and above - No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, confluent-kafka-python

After migrating python version from 3.7 to 3.8/3.9, seeing an issue with Kafka confluent compatibility in one of our Lambda functions. I am using Kafka confluent 1.6 library.

Error while running lambda:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'pzn-kafka-emitter': No module named 
  'confluent_kafka.cimpl'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the confluent library vs `kafka-python`?